# How to validate if an Account exists?

Tags: accounts, smart-contract

I know that we have `require_auth` to check for permission, but I'm looking for something like `is_valid_account` to check if the account exists and is active in the chain.

Do we have anything like that? I tried to use `eosio.token` contract to transfer tokens to a non-existing account and it just allowed me to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: I noticed that if we call `require_recipient` and the account does not exist the action will fail... but not sure if it's the best practice because doing that we always "notify" the recipient account

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it in Dawn 4.0 release, it's simply `is_account(account_name)`

Check out the `eosio.token` new contract in transfer action, release: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/dawn-v4.0.0/contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.cpp#L76

`eosio_assert( is_account( to ), "to account does not exist");`

Answer (score 5):

There's a new intrinsic in the `slim` branch, but isn't declared yet in a header.

`extern "C" int64_t get_account_creation_date(account_name account);`

It looks like this function will fail if the account doesn't exist.

Comment: that's cool... What is the meaning of this `slim` branch?

Comment: It's the branch that Dawn 4.0 is being developed on. Dan introduced it at https://medium.com/eosio/introducing-eosio-dawn-4-0-f738c552879